# Korean SAT math question help please.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I tried things but failed to get f'(5) - g'(5). HELP!

Comment: yeah it is f(t)-g(t) + t(f'(t)-g'(t))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(t)$ is a root of the equation
$$
x^3+2x^2-15x+5-t=0\\
\implies f^3+2f^2-15f+5-t=0\\
$$
which upon differentiation yields
$$
\implies 3f^2f'+4ff'-15f'-1=0\\
\implies f'={1\over3f^2+4f-15}\cdots(1)
$$
Similarly $g(t)$ satisfies
$$
g'={1\over3g^2+4g-15}\cdots(2)
$$
Now $f(5),g(5)$ are roots of
$$
x^3+2x^2-15x=0
$$
which can be easily solved. Therefore we know $f(5),g(5)$. Consequently from $(1),(2)$ we know $f'(5),g'(5)$. These are all we need to figure out $h'(5)$.

Comment: Why f(5) is a root of $x^3+2x^2-15x=0$?

Comment: @EugenCovaci Plug in $t=5$ in $x^3+2x^2-15x+5-t$ to get the required eqn.